# Is there a working dojo tabContainer can successfully reload in a contentPane?

Tags: javascript, dom, dojo

I am not lazy but have tried many ways try to reload a div(id=refreshable) which contains a dojo TabContainer(id=dojoTabbedPane). Each time after reloading the page all content in each tab show up one a stack(the tabs are missing).

I did some research, ask questions, and use `dijit.byId("dojoTabbedPane").destroyRecursive();` before jQuery load and then call `dojo.parser.parse(dojo.byId("dojoTabbedPane"));` after re load but never works.

So, please, can anyone share a simple snippet can actually show me that a tabContainer can look all right its container is refreshed? I swear I try many theoretical way to and it should work but can anyone show me a very simple code to let me see it works?

I don't know how to paste big chunk of code here otherwise I will give a base sample so everyone is interested can help to revise, here I have prepared a tabContainer from Dojo website, please help me to work it out. Thanks !!

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="dojo/dojo/dojo.js"  
djConfig="parseOnLoad: true"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript" >
function refresh_data(url, id) {
j('#'+id).load(url+' #'+id+' > *', function (response) {
      dojo.parser.parse(dojo.byId("dojoTabbedPane"));
});
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var login_url = '<spring:url value="/login" />';

    j(function() {
        setInterval('refresh_data("file:///D:/Dojo/dojo.tabbed.pane_very_good.html?hash="+Math.random(), "refreshable");', 9000); 
    });
    // this disables errors in IE7
    function noError(){return true;}
    window.onerror = noError;
</script>
<style type="text/css"> 
@import "dojo/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css"; 
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
dojo.require("dojo.parser");
dojo.require("dijit.layout.TabContainer");
dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
</script>
</head>
<body class="tundra">
    <!-- this div is only for documentation purpose, in real development environments, just take it out -->
<div style="width: 350px; height: 300px">
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.TabContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="My first tab" selected="false">
        Lorem ipsum and all around...
    </div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="My second tab"  selected="true">
        Lorem ipsum and all around - second...
    </div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="My last tab" closable="true">
        Lorem ipsum and all around - last...
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: im sorry to say that your question raises more questions then it asks, refine it a bit please. Problem youre facing is, tabcontainer gets destroyed when contentholder is 'refreshed' and you need to rebuild it. *Where is 'refreshable'* and does it has a width/height set? *Why is there a jquery call?* :) How does *returned html from file:///* look like?

Comment: You need to parse the "refreshable" div, not the "dojoTabbedPane" div that you put inside it.

Comment: @mschr Sorry for the confusion. The requirement asks for auto refreshing of part of the page(what in the div 'refreshable'), so I call javascript function setInterval to call $JQuery.load every 30s. The reason I use jQuery is because dojo.xhrGet cannot handle large set of data. The 'refreshable' doesn't have width/height. the relation is more like `<div id='refreshable'><div id='dojoTabbedPane'>....</div></div>`(here i ignore the content and dojo-type etc..). Please share any opinion. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: @Frode Thanks a lot for the answer again :D. Shall I do the parse of 'refreshable' div before the jQuery load or within the jQuery load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a question regarding jQuery, whether or not load has allready set innerHTML of the #replaceable at the time the complete callback runs.. But simply uncomment the timeout lines to 'unhook' and let load mechanism finish before calling parser. So try this:

```
<div id="replaceable">

</div>

<script>
function refresh_data(url, id) {

  var w = dijit.byId("dojoTabbedPane"),
      domNode = dojo.byId(id);
  if(w)  w.destroyRecursive();

  j(domNode).load(url+' #'+id+' > *', function (response) {
      // setTimeout(function() {
         dojo.parser.parse(domNode);
         w = dijit.byId("dojoTabbedPane");
         w.resize(dojo.getMarginBox(domNode));
      // }, 200);

  });
}

dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
    var login_url = '<spring:url value="/login" />';
    setInterval('refresh_data("file:///D:/Dojo/dojo.tabbed.pane_very_good.html?hash="+Math.random(), "refreshable");', 9000); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: That's a wonderful feedback and thank you very much. However the contents within that tabContainer still show up on a stack without the tags even when I uncomment the setTimeout in jQuery. So I guess there maybe issues specifically in Dojo TabContainer to get rendered after reloaded? It seems the tabContainer can never look alright after parsed again.

Comment: @Subarule: Does the tab container look right the first time (before refresh_data has replaced it with a new one)? If I recall correctly, if the tabs cannot fit the in the given space (e.g. if the width is too small), the tabs become a drop-down menu instead. Is that the case? See my attempt here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/zdSZq/

Comment: @Frode Yes it works fine the first time and the rest of the time after refreshing there is no tab at all. I see the only difference here is I am still on dojo 1.6.1 Does that could be a problem? Thanks

Comment: @Frode Oh, that's wonderful tools to test out snipplet. Actually I switch to Dojo1.6 and it works. But the tabContainer seems just refresh only one time, I though the setInterval should repeatingly work constantly?

Comment: @Frode And also I see that the `newContentFromServer` include divs of dojoTabbedPane and contentPanes which I am not sure the refreshable from my page can return the same back to current page.

Comment: @Subarule Actually, with 1.6, I could only get it working if I switched to using "dojoType" instead of "data-dojo-type". I thought 1.6 supported both, but I may be wrong. Before 1.6 you had to use dojoType.

Comment: Perhaps it just looks like it refreshes once because I replace it with the same content every time :)

Comment: for a tabcontainer to layout correctly, it has to have the set dimension from either 1) in its own style attribute 2) in the containing nodes style (be it calculated from stylesheet or not). As i recall, calling tabContainer.resize() with no arguments makes it fill up what it can - if parentNode has a calculateable height/width

Comment: Frode and mschr. Wonderful answers, very lucky to meet professionals as you two fellows, Thanks again ! :D