# TabContainer refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, dojo

I have multiple tabs created using dojo in a page, i want to refresh the page every **5** seconds but just want to refresh the current tab which iam pointing to every 5seconds. Please find the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5yn2hLv9/4/ .

Below is the sample code:

```
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer" style="width: 100%;height: 100px" tabStrip="true">
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="First tab" selected="true">
        11
    </div>
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Second tab">
        2222
    </div>
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Last tab">
        333333
    </div>
</div>
```

--EDIT--

After every 5 seconds when page refreshes , all 3 tabs data is shown on the page and page is loading , i want to avoid showing all the tabs data on the page while its loading, as in my application each tab contains lot of data and each time it is refreshing it shows lot of data which is getting from all the tabs.

Comment: Can you tell me why you need to refresh? is there new data coming from an ajax call ?

Comment: @dorinaji - data would be coming from database and i need to refresh the screen to show the latest data.

Answer (score 1):

It is true what xaris08 said about loading the tabs without reloading the page, you should use the tab specific ajax which I recommend, but to answer you question if you are stuck with the reload page which I would not recommend you can do some dirty way like the code below.

```
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer" style="width: 100%;height: 100px" tabStrip="true">
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="First tab" selected="true">
     <div id="content1"></div>
    </div>
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Second tab">
     <div id="content2"></div>
    </div>
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Last tab">
       <div id="content3"></div>
    </div>
</div>



require(["dijit/layout/TabContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dojo/parser"]);

  setTimeout(function () { location.reload(true);}, 8000);

    require(["dojo/html", "dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!"],
    function(html, dom, on){
     setTimeout(function () { 
       html.set(dom.byId("content1"), "11");
       html.set(dom.byId("content2"), "22222");
       html.set(dom.byId("content3"), "33333333");
               }, 1000);


  });
```

This way every time you load the page you give sometime for the tabs to render and one second is enough then you inject the values in the dom using the html.set. look at it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5yn2hLv9/7/)

Answer (score 0):

You should put an id in the outer div element (container) and you will then be able to get the selected tab with:

```js
dijit.byId('id_of_outer_div').selectedChildWidget
```

But I am not sure if you can reload with location.reload() only with the specific tab.

Comment: After every 5 seconds when page refreshes , all 3 tabs data is shown on the page and page is loading , i want to avoid showing all the tabs data on the page while its is loading, as in my application each tab contains lot of data and each time it refreshing its displaying lot of data which id getting from all the tabs. @xaris08 .

Comment: I am not sure if I get you but if you want to refresh the whole page (location.reload()) and refresh only the selected tab I am afraid you cannot do it and it is reasonably that reloads all 3 tabs. Otherwise, if you want to reload only specific tab you may use tab-specific AJAX call requests (xhrGet() function) to reload each tab.

Please have a look on that if it helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889319/is-there-a-working-dojo-tabcontainer-can-successfully-reload-in-a-contentpane